# \t string with sed

Tags: sed

I'm using sed to replace the string "\UPo" by the string "\textit{Old (User's preferences)}".
The command I'm using is:

```
find /home/rom/Desktop/nodeRemoval/report -name \*.tex -exec sed -i "s/\\UPo/\\textit{Old (User's preferences)}/g" {} \;
```

I want to escape the backslashes as they are part of the string. But instead of a backslash it gives me a tab!
The output is: \[TAB]extit{Old (User's preferences)}

What's wrong?

Thanks in advance,

Rom

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your expression is in double quotes, the string gets evaluated by bash (which replaces `\\` with `\`). In fact, the regex passed on to sed looks like that:

```
s/\UPo/\textit{Old (User's preferences)}/g
```

Either escape each backslash twice:

```
sed -i "s/\\\\UPo/\\\\textit{Old (User's preferences)}/g"
```

or, better, use single quotes. Anything in single quotes will not get evaluated by bash, but beware: a single quote may not appear between single quotes, so you need to finish the single quote, escape single quote, start single quote again:

```
sed -i "s/\\UPo/\\textit{Old (User'\''s preferences)}/g"
```

This is all a bit silly, which is why we have Perl.